# processBitmap - java.lang.IllegalStateException and java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I doesn't why I am getting these stacktrace error.My problem is now I can't able to view the images.

**Stacktrace:**

```
 E/ImageFetcher(1309): processBitmap - java.lang.IllegalStateException:
 edit didn't create file 0

 E/Error(1309)       : org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 2 of   

 E/ImageFetcher(1309): Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
 E/ImageFetcher(1309): Error in downloadBitmap - java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

 E/ImageFetcher(1309): processBitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.gems.android/cache/http/ec1de446b4ed202c22d7c762f1746668.0.tmp: fstat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**ImageFetcher.java:**

```
package com.sit.fth.util;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
//import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gems.android.BuildConfig;

public class ImageFetcher extends ImageResizer {
    private static final String TAG = "ImageFetcher";
    private static final int HTTP_CACHE_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10MB
    private static final String HTTP_CACHE_DIR = "http";
    private static final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;

    private DiskLruCache mHttpDiskCache;
    private File mHttpCacheDir;
    private boolean mHttpDiskCacheStarting = true;
    private final Object mHttpDiskCacheLock = new Object();
    private static final int DISK_CACHE_INDEX = 0;

    public ImageFetcher(Context context, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
        super(context, imageWidth, imageHeight);
        init(context);
    }


    public ImageFetcher(Context context, int imageSize) {
        super(context, imageSize);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        checkConnection(context);
        mHttpCacheDir = ImageCache.getDiskCacheDir(context, HTTP_CACHE_DIR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initDiskCacheInternal() {
        super.initDiskCacheInternal();
        initHttpDiskCache();
    }

    private void initHttpDiskCache() {
        if (!mHttpCacheDir.exists()) {
            mHttpCacheDir.mkdirs();
        }
        synchronized (mHttpDiskCacheLock) {
            if (ImageCache.getUsableSpace(mHttpCacheDir) > HTTP_CACHE_SIZE) {
                try {
                    mHttpDiskCache = DiskLruCache.open(mHttpCacheDir, 1, 1, HTTP_CACHE_SIZE);
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        AppLog.d(TAG, "HTTP cache initialized");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    mHttpDiskCache = null;
                }
            }
            mHttpDiskCacheStarting = false;
            mHttpDiskCacheLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void clearCacheInternal() {
        super.clearCacheInternal();
        synchronized (mHttpDiskCacheLock) {
            if (mHttpDiskCache != null && !mHttpDiskCache.isClosed()) {
                try {
                    mHttpDiskCache.delete();
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        AppLog.d(TAG, "HTTP cache cleared");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "clearCacheInternal - " + e);
                }
                mHttpDiskCache = null;
                mHttpDiskCacheStarting = true;
                initHttpDiskCache();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void flushCacheInternal() {
        super.flushCacheInternal();
        synchronized (mHttpDiskCacheLock) {
            if (mHttpDiskCache != null) {
                try {
                    mHttpDiskCache.flush();
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        AppLog.d(TAG, "HTTP cache flushed");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "flush - " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void closeCacheInternal() {
        super.closeCacheInternal();
        synchronized (mHttpDiskCacheLock) {
            if (mHttpDiskCache != null) {
                try {
                    if (!mHttpDiskCache.isClosed()) {
                        mHttpDiskCache.close();
                        mHttpDiskCache = null;
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            AppLog.d(TAG, "HTTP cache closed");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "closeCacheInternal - " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void checkConnection(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AppLog.e(TAG, "checkConnection - no connection found");
        }
    }



    private Bitmap processBitmap(String data) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            AppLog.d(TAG, "processBitmap - " + data);
        }

        final String key = ImageCache.hashKeyForDisk(data);
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot;
        synchronized (mHttpDiskCacheLock) {
            // Wait for disk cache to initialize
            while (mHttpDiskCacheStarting) {
                try {
                    mHttpDiskCacheLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

            if (mHttpDiskCache != null) {
                try {
                    snapshot = mHttpDiskCache.get(key);
                    if (snapshot == null) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            AppLog.d(TAG, "processBitmap, not found in http cache, downloading...");
                        }
                        DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mHttpDiskCache.edit(key);
                        if (editor != null) {
                            if (downloadUrlToStream(data,
                                    editor.newOutputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX))) {
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                editor.abort();
                            }
                        }
                        snapshot = mHttpDiskCache.get(key);
                    }
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        fileInputStream =
                                (FileInputStream) snapshot.getInputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX);
                        fileDescriptor = fileInputStream.getFD();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "processBitmap - " + e);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    AppLog.e(TAG, "processBitmap - " + e);
                } finally {
                    if (fileDescriptor == null && fileInputStream != null) {
                        try {
                            fileInputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (fileDescriptor != null) {
            bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromDescriptor(fileDescriptor, mImageWidth,
                    mImageHeight, getImageCache());
        }
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
        return processBitmap(String.valueOf(data));
    }


    public boolean downloadUrlToStream(String urlString, OutputStream outputStream) {
        disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {
            final URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(b);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            AppLog.e(TAG, "Error in downloadBitmap - " + e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {}
        }
        return false;
    }


    public static void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
        // HTTP connection reuse which was buggy pre-froyo
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gems.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.gems.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.gems.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.sit.fth.app.GemsApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.HomeActivity" >
        </activity>
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.GalleryActivity" >
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.AnnouncementActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.MagazineActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.fth.activity.YoutubePlayActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

It doesn't show the images.It seems that it always loading the image.Finally I cant get the actual image as a output.

Anybody can help me if you know how to solve these.Thank You.

Comment: full stack trace is always better than a single line :)

Comment: @nizammoidu yes posted full stacktrace.

Comment: do you have root access  on the device ? 
never mind you are writing to sdcard do have permissions set

Comment: I think you are trying to download from a url where image does not exists.

Comment: @AshwinNBhanushali no.definitely Images exist there.I think there was a problem here `processBitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.gems.android/cache/http/ec1de446b4ed202c22d7c762f1746668.0.tmp: fstat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @nizammoidu I am using sdcard in emulator

Comment: @Stephen then from stack trace it's clear that file does not exist on the sdcard.that's why you are getting No such file or directory

Comment: @AshwinNBhanushali Then what I have to do? always emulator creating some new problem for few days.Many times I created the new emulator.

Comment: @Stephen which is API level ? what are the permssions in your manifest?

Comment: @nizammoidu posted manifest.check out that.

Comment: permisions seems to oky can you put `e.printStackTrace()` after all `AppLog.e(TAG, "processBitmap - " + e);` or configure AppLog to full stack trace ?

Comment: @nizammoidu where I have to add that lines in `private Bitmap processBitmap(String data)`

Comment: yes in processBitmap and are you able to see the images in sdcard  through a file browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly In my `emulator` there was a `two app` in the `same name`.I doesn't know that.

That's why I am getting these Exception at RunTime.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.gems.android/cache/http/ec1de446b4ed202c22d7c76‌​2f1746668.0.tmp:
>   fstat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I solved these problem by uninstall the two same app name and install the currently worked project.